# Not getting Country name by geo location

Tags: magento-1.9, geoip

I am trying to get country name by `Geo-location`. so i used Geo plugin but not working good. its show all good by browser url. but when i am trying to set response by `php` its not return anything.

I don't know what is issue with my code.

Geoip Url : http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=xx.xx.xx.xx

> require_once('geoplugin.class.php');

```
 $geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
    $geoplugin->locate();
    if($geoplugin->countryCode){
        $_SESSION['cCode'] = $geoplugin->countryCode;
    }else{
        $_SESSION['cCode'] = "US";
    }
```

Comment: I would be easier if you can share geoplugin URL in your question

Comment: @ShoaibMunir check my updated question

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: @ShoaibMunir yes we resolve this issue

Comment: Can you tell us what was the issue?

Comment: we need to verify our domain in geoplugin website.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it correctly, the issue that you are facing is may be due to localhost.

Try above code by passing hard codded IP for testing purpose, like this:

```
$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$yourIp = "206.189.146.36";
$geoplugin->locate();
if ($geoplugin->countryCode) {
    $_SESSION['cCode'] = $geoplugin->countryCode;
} else {
    $_SESSION['cCode'] = "US";
}
```

When you are accessing geoplugin API through URL, then geoplugin is fetching you IP address, but from local host it would fetching `127.0.0.1` or something like this

Hope you find your answer.